# Is there a way to run universal apps on Firebase Hosting?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have recently deployed my Angular 2 application to Firebase hosting successfully and am really enjoying this set up so far, particularly on how easy it is to deploy using CI as well.

At the moment, I am looking at adding a universal server rendering support to my app, but I'm not sure if this is handled by Firebase Hosting, as it says it is static file only.

However, what made me think that this could be a potential feature that I am missing is that Firebase offers support for single page applications, hence I decided to ask.

If there isn't support for such apps, can we expect it in the future?

Comment: I'm also interested in this, and I searched for same answers few months back. But the answer is: no, not at the moment. I'm looking at Heroku for *Universal* at this time...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible. However since Angular 2, Google and Firebase go hand in hand I would say this it is just a matter of time.

In the meantime you can create a Node.js-based server, where you install Angular Universal, and have it connect to Firebase with the Firebase Node SDK.

Next, you simply communicate with that Node-backend from your Angular 2 application.

Comment: I like how this "Angular 2, Google and Firebase go hand in hand I would say this it is just a matter of time."

Answer (score 0):

If you're using angularfire2, that will break universal either way. There's something in the package that calls "window" which doesn't exist on the server. Unless something changes with universal or angularfire this is a ways off

Answer (score 0):

At the end of that video David East mentions that one can use Google Cloud Functions with Angular Universal and such: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3v8EcYzf_M

The video itself is quite useful for firebase users. But the topic starts at approximately 23:30.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to skip universal altogether and do something like [this](https://www.skillmapped.com/blog/server-side-rendering).

Rendertron is a headless chrome that can be launched. Similar to phantomjs. But universal gives speed.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.